# How to implement swipe views with CollectionView/TableView Controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swipe, navigationbar

I am creating an app using Swift, **and I'm still trying to figure out what the best configuration would be.**
What I'd like to have is **3 screens** (the left screen would have a side out panel) **that users can access via the navigation bar menu or just by swiping left/right the screen for more accessibility.**

I could easily create my TableViewControllers/CollectionViewController and the menu, but I'm struggling at making the screen able to detect users gestures at the same time, and I'm not sure **whether I should use 3 View Controllers and then add the Collection View/Table View via the Storyboard, or directly use the CollectionViewController/TableViewController**

I added a picture here describing what I'd like to accomplish:

[image: Draft of what I would like to accomplish]

**Also, I wonder whether I should use storyboards or not for my project.**

I know that's a lot of questions !

Any ideas please ?

Thank you very much and have a good day,

J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add 2 "swipe gesture recogniser"s to your middle screen(your second screen in your attached image) , and set one for identifying left swipe and another for right swipe. Create action methods for both in your view controller and add code accessing left screen and right screen in respective methods.

note - you need to drag "swipe gesture recogniser" to top bar of your view controller scene to add it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  I tried to use the swipe gesture recognizer as you said, but I'm facing a SIGABRT error every time I run the simulator, even with a simplified code (I tried with and without the storyboard). Looks like I'm having issues with the Swipe Recognizer. If you have any ideas what that error could be coming from, it would help me a lot !

Comment: Here is the code :
`class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
 
    @IBOutlet weak var swipeView: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        
            let aSelector : Selector = "handleSwipe:"
            let swipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: aSelector)
            swipeGesture.direction = [.down, .up]
            self.swipeView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)
    }
   
    func handleSwipe(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer)
    {
            print(sender.direction)
    }`

Comment: Thank you, all solved now : my selector syntax was incorrect. The proper syntax to use is `#selector(ClassName.methodName(_:))`. Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scrollview as a container, put three ViewController in it.

Comment: Problem solved?  If the solution can solve your problem.Vote for it to help more people.

Comment: Thanks, I could finally solve my problem using a scrollview and creating programatically 3 ViewControllers     `let vc1 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController1")` and so on for vc2 and vc3. I then added them as subviews of my scrollview and this all work out as it should !